# Android Wallpaper as background

Tags: live-wallpaper, wallpaper

How can I scroll wallpaper and send touch events to live wallpapers set as app backround.
It is possible using @android:style/Theme.Wallpaper?

Comment: What does the official documentation have to say about that?

Comment: Nothing about scrolling and sending touch events. Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Your English is perfect so far. BTW what I did there was a bit of rubber ducking... If that didn't solve your problem, well, I hope you get a good answer from someone who knows more than we do. Anyway, +1.

Answer (score 0):

Use the onOffsetsChanged() method for scrolling of wallpaper and onTouchEvent() mwthod to send touch events which are available in Engine class.